# Quilljs Text 'Regions'

Tags: quill

What is the best strategy to use within QuillJS ( blots, containers etc ) to essentially create what appears to be a single 'document' in the Quilljs editor but is, in fact, multiple regions that are saved separately?

For example, a quilljs instance looks like the following:

---

**Some title 1**
Some text one and more text for one and yet some more.

**Some title 2**
Some text two and more text for two and yet some more.

---

When the user hits a save button I would like to extract the text below each title ( example: Some title 1 ) and save the user's text separately ( example: Some text one etc. ).

Do I have to parse the delta object to achieve this or can I wrap the text below the title sections in a unique object that I can then extract the delta from?

Comment: What are these "Some title 1" and "Some title 2"? Do you render these? Could the user edit them?

Comment: All of the content within each of these blots is completely editable. Here is the link to a google doc that illustrates the need a bit more. Thanks for the assistance.

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/11cmvcWkkeE-8KYWkksY7yLyOby52So3AsIv1u0rw-LI/edit?usp=sharing